# python nested dictionaries to store usernames and passwords

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, hash, nested, multiple-users

What I'm trying to create is a dictionary that stores hashed usernames and passwords from user input... Now admittedly I don't think I fully understand how nested dictionaries work but here is the code of my function so far:

```
users = {}    
def addUser():
    print """"
    ########
    Add user
    ########
    """
    while True:
        username = hashlib.sha512(raw_input("Enter username: ")).hexdigest()
        passwd = hashlib.sha512(raw_input("Enter password: ")).hexdigest()
        uid = int(username[:5], 16) % 32

        users[username + passwd] = {
            'User hash':username,
            'Password hash':passwd,
            }

        print users
        cont = raw_input("Press 'X/x' to exit and start the server or ANY other key to continue adding users: ")
        if cont in ['X', 'x']:
            break
```

What I want to do is use the `uid` variable to generate a unique identifier for each user and store it in a nested dictionary that will look something like this:

```
users = { 'uid': 28 { 'User hash': 'BFCDF3E6CA6CEF45543BFBB57509C92AEC9A39FB', 'Password hash': '9D989E8D27DC9E0EC3389FC855F142C3D40F0C50'},'uid': 10 { 'User hash': '8C4947E96C7C9F770AA386582E32CE7CE1B96E69', 'Password hash': '266F83D202FA3DA4A075CEA751B4B8D6A30DA1A8'}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question after doing some reading and playing around with the code.

Here's the solved code if anyone else is having a similar issue

```
import hashlib

users = {}
def addUser()
    print """"
    ########
    Add user
    ########
    """
    while True:
    username = hashlib.sha512(raw_input("Enter username: ")).hexdigest()    #use SHA512 to hash username from raw input
    uid = int(username[:5], 16) % 32                                        #generate uid from hashed username, using math simliar to the chord algorithm but with SHA512 instead of SHA1
    passwd = hashlib.sha512(raw_input("Enter password: ")).hexdigest()      #use SHA512 to hash password from raw input


    users[uid] = {   #store username and password in dictionary 
        'User hash':username,
        'Password hash':passwd,
        }


    print users
    cont = raw_input("Press 'X/x' to exit and start the server or ANY other key to continue adding users: ")
    if cont in ['X', 'x']:
        break
```

I figured it out by looking at what the `print users` call actually did and it printed a combination of the two hashes, so replacing `users[username + passwd]` with `users[uid]` solved the issue!

Moral of the story: If it doesn't work... Do some research, have a play around & Try harder! ;)